How to Add a GraphQL Mutation using HotChocolate with Schema Stitching?
I’m working on a .NET Core project using HotChocolate as my GraphQL server. I’m trying to implement Schema Stitching from multiple services, and while I’ve been successful with Queries, I’m having trouble with Mutations.
I'm just doing a POC and I have defined the classes in this way
[ExtendObjectType("Query")]
public class Query
{
    private ProfileRepository _repo;

    public Query()
    {
        _repo = ProfileRepository.GetInstance();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Profile> GetProfiles()
    {
        return _repo.GetProfiles();
    }
}


public class Mutation
{
    private ProfileRepository _repo;

    public Mutation()
    {
        _repo = ProfileRepository.GetInstance();
    }

    public Profile AddProfile(int operationId, string externalId, DateTime createdAt)
    {       
        Profile profile = new Profile
        {
            ExternalId = externalId,
            CreatedAt = createdAt,
            OperationId = operationId,
        };

        return profile; 
    }
}

public class ProfileRepository
{
    private static ProfileRepository _instance;
    private List<Profile> _profiles;

    private ProfileRepository()
    {
        _profiles = new List<Profile>(50);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            _profiles.Add(new Profile
            {
                Id = i + 1,
                OperationId = 100 + i,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-i),
                ExternalId  = $"ExternalId{i + 1}"
            });
        }
    }

    public static ProfileRepository GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new ProfileRepository();
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    public List<Profile> GetProfiles() { return _profiles; }

    public Profile AddProfile(Profile newProfile) {

        int lastId = _profiles
           .OrderByDescending(p => p.Id)
           .First()
           .Id;

        newProfile.Id = lastId;
        _profiles.Add (newProfile);

        return newProfile;
    }
}


This is my configuration
services.AddHttpClient("externalService", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(airaDataRepositoryOptions.ApiUrl);
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            $"{airaDataRepositoryOptions.ApiUsername}:{airaDataRepositoryOptions.ApiPassword}"
        );
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)
    );
});

services.AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddTypeExtension<Query>()
    .AddRemoteSchema("externalService")
    .AddMutationType<Mutation>();

When I add the method AddMutationType<Mutation>() I get this exception:
 The schema builder was unable to identify the query type of the schema. 
Either specify which type is the query type or set the schema builder to non-strict validation mode.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly add a GraphQL mutation using HotChocolate with Schema Stitching?
